# Line strokes also adding borders to other shapes?

Tags: javascript, html-canvas

When you run the [project](https://repl.it/@phruut/Note-practice#script.js), you can see that the first circles have a black border around them. When I remove the `Game.drawLines()`, the circles don't have the border around them anymore. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I remove the `Game.drawLines()`, the circles don't have the border around them anymore.

Well, let's do the obvious thing and look at that function then.

```
  static drawLines() {
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
    for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      ctx.moveTo(0, i * (canvas.width / 50) + 50);
      ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, i * (canvas.width / 50) + 50);
      ctx.stroke();
    }
  }
```

Now let's contrast it against your other drawing function:

```
  static drawNotes() {
    for(let i of notes) {
      ctx.fillStyle = i.selected ? "#E95500" : "#000000";
      ctx.globalAlpha = i.opacity;
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(i.x + i.xOffset, i.y + i.yOffset, i.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.closePath();
    }
  }
```

What's missing? In the `drawNotes` function, we `beginPath()` before drawing each disc, resetting the stored path so each one is drawn in isolation.

But in `drawLines`, we're missing this. So whatever path we drew most recently is *still stored inside the context*, just waiting to be stroked when we call `ctx.stroke()`.

It looks like you were trying to use `ctx.closePath()` to "end" the path, but that's not what this function does. It "closes" the path in the sense that it connects the endpoint back to the start point, so if you stroke it you'll see a closed loop. But the shape isn't "dropped" after you close it, it's still part of the current drawing path until you `beginPath()` again to clear it out and start a fresh path to stroke/fill/etc.

So, `beginPath()` before you draw your lines, or after you draw your notes, to ensure drawing state from one function doesn't leak over into the other.

Comment: Oh wow, I thought `beginPath` was just a thing you just put in front of your paths. Thanks for the info!